# send image from one activity to another

Tags: java, android, android-activity

I am trying to send an image from one activity to another but I dont know how to set the imageview.

here is how I send the image and other stuff

```
Intent item_intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Item.class);
item_intent.putExtra("name","test name arif");
item_intent.putExtra("quantity","99");
//*************************here is the image***************************
item_intent.putExtra("image",R.drawable.access);
MainActivity.this.startActivity(item_intent);
```

here is how I am trying to read the image and set it to the ImageView but I am getting a syntax error.

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
ImageView img_view = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.item_image);

// this where I am having problem below******************************
img_view.setImageBitmap(intent.getByteArrayExtra("image"));
```

how should I set the ImageView?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Dont you think

```
img_view.setImageBitmap(intent.getByteArrayExtra("quantity"));
```

should be

```
img_view.setImageResource(intent.getIntExtra("name",R.drawable.default_image));
```

Answer (score 0):

use this code for get intent

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
    ImageView img_view = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.item_image);
    img_view.setBackgroundResource(intent.getIntExtra("name",1));
```

Comment: for string "name" you use "image"